# How to Downgrade Bootloader or eeprom RPi4 2GB

Tags: pi-4, retropie, pi4-eeprom

I'm as new as it gets to the RPi world. Trying to set up a retro-gaming (yep, I'm one of those). I'm on a RPi4 2GB and I have an image flashed to my drive and when trying to boot, I get the following (along with all the rest):

> Firmware: 99d9a48302e4553cff3688692bb7e9ac760a03fa Jan 27 2021 22:20:57
> 0x00b03115 0x00000000 0x0000003f
> start.elf: is not compatible
> This board requires newer software

My logic is telling me that the software on the image I am trying to use is outdated (even though it is set up for a pi4) and can't boot with the current bootloader.

I've tried all I can to roll back the bootloader to older versions and can only go back so far before I need to use the raspberry pi imager to create a bootloader restore disk and go back to the "start"

So I guess my main question is how do I get this image to boot? I'd like to just roll back the eeprom and firmware to about a year ago so that way the image I have can work (it was only made about 6 months ago by the original creator)

So... How do I downgrade my hardware eeprom (bootloader) form one of the older stable builds found on raspberry pi's github (https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/tree/master/firmware) without bricking the thing and having to start over (which is been my result so far)?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably be better off putting a newer version of `start.elf` etc in the image, just don't replace any of the `kernel.img` files (since these are paired with modules in the root fs).  That *may* (but probably will not, I'm just guessing it is possible) cause a conflict with the kernel, but it is at least worth a try (by doing it on a card and testing that).

Comment: start4.elf, start4x.elf, start4cd.elf, and start4db.elf are firmware files specific to the Raspberry Pi 4 - it does not use start.elf

Comment: As suggested in comments, I replaced the start.elf and this didn't quite work. I'd get past the boot error, but it would then just go to blank screen and I couldn't ssh into it either.
I did, however, find that creating a fresh new image of "recalbox" and copying all the contents of it's "RECALBOX" share into my original image's "RECALBOX" share got it to work. I am going to do a bit of fine tuning, but I think this will eventually get it working. Thanks for your suggestions @goldilocks & others.

Comment: @allen8r84 If this turns out to be a lasting solution, please consider writing it up in detail as an answer yourself; I believe you should be allowed to do that 24 hours after the question was posted.